# Principles for creating universal app

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, universal

I am in process of creating a new universal application.

Would it be "bad" or against guidelines to create separate classes to control the iPad version?

I am using a tabbarcontroller for the iPhone version and a splitview for the iPad version.

It seems easier in my case to create new classes to handle all the iPad stuff.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, not bad or against guidelines at all.

In my own universal apps, I use separate XIB's for iPad versus iPhone interfaces.  And sometimes different (or additional) classes for iPads as well.

Probably one of the more important things is that the functionality is roughly the same between iPad & iPhone versions... will the tab bar view do the same thing the split view do, for example?

Comment: Yep, it will have almost the same functionality. I do a lot of drawing and animation programmatically so it will be easier to just have new classes.

Comment: As Michael mentions, there are no guidelines at all for how you write your code ... only guidelines about what the user can actually see. You can check for iPad vs. iPhone and diverge into completely different sets of code if you'd like. Apple just wants the Apps to be consistent on both, and to follow their Human User Interface guidelines.